# Python: How to initialise a OOP List with some values already known?

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to get into Object Oriented Programming but am getting stuck on something which is probably very simple. I want to have an object which is a list, but which starts with having some values passed into it.

Example:

```
class superList(list):
    def __init__(self,startingValues):
        self = startingValues

myList = superList([1,2,3])
myList.append(4)
print(myList)
```

I want the output of this to be [1,2,3,4]. If anyone could help, I would be very thankful!

Comment: Don't inherit from `list` or other built-in types. It rarely ends well. Also, I don't see how your class is any different from a normal list.

Comment: It is currently the same as list, but I will be adding some more methods to it later. Are there any other ways of getting an object to have list-like behaviour? (eg. myList[3] = "bacon")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assigning to `self` isn't useful; you are just assigning to a local name that goes away after `__init__` returns. Instead, you need to use `__new__`, and call the parent's class's `__new__` method.

```
class SuperList(list):
    def __new__(cls, starting_values):
        return list.__new__(cls, starting_values)
```

Another approach is to use `__init__`, and just append the values in place:

```
class SuperList(list):
    def __init__(self, starting_values):
        self.extend(starting_values)
```

As pointed out in the comments, though, you would get the exact same result by not overriding either method:

```
class SuperList(list):
    pass
```

because you aren't doing anything except invoking parent-class behavior in either method. In the absence of a defined `SuperList.__new__`, for example, `SuperList([1,2,3])` just calls `list.__new__(SuperList, [1,2,3])` anyway.

More interesting is when the class itself (at least, in part) determines behavior beyond using the values passed by the caller. For example:

```
class SuperList(list):
    def __init__(self, starting_values):
        self.extend([2*x for x in starting_values])
```

or

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.extend([1,2,3])
```

Comment: This is brilliant! That second approach is perfect. Have a great day chepner!

Comment: chepner, curious, why explicit `list.__new__(cls, starting_values)` instead of `super().__new__(cls, starting_values)`?

Comment: I try not to emphasize `super` as an all-purpose replacement for a single parent class. Using `super` has a specific semantic meaning, which is not better or worse than hardcoding the parent class, just different.

Answer (score 1):

Don't inherit from built-in types, at least not as a beginner and without having read the actual implementation of those built-in's.

What you could do is writting a wrapper, something along the lines of this:

```
class MyList(object):

    def __init__(self, init_values):
        self.myList = []
        self.myList.extend(init_values)

    def append(self, value):
        self.myList.append(value)

    def __getitem__(self, _slice):
        return self.myList[_slice]
```

NOTE: this is just to give you an idea of how you could do what you wanted to do, you would have to implement some additional cases and methods to actually have most functionalities of the builtin.